# Returning an error code from CMD to Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm working on a Mssql install script and I want to get the results of a silent mssql installation. In my PowerShell script I run this command:

```
$result = (start cmd "/c D:\SQL2008R2\SQL2008R2\setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=sqlconfig.ini && exit 0 || exit 1")
```

Which should return 0 on fail and 1 on pass. Unfortunately, I don't get any output back. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not how `&&` works, and you can't choose `exit 0` or `exit 1` after the setup runs. You have to test `ERRORLEVEL`, and that's typically done in a batch file, which could then exit with the appropriate error code.

Comment: Well, it actually does work like that. `&&` runs the left side and if it's false (the command failed) then it runs the right side of the `&&`. Operator precedence groups `(Left && Middle) || Right`. Now that I think about it, if `||` is a conditional-or and only runs until a true value, then I should have actually used `&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to `Start-Process` is the more syntactically terse call operator `&`.

```
& cmd.exe /c 'ping.exe doesnotexist && exit 0 || exit 1'
```

The exit code will be contained in the built-in variable `$LASTEXITCODE` so:

```
Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE
```

This will contain the exit code of the program run so you don't necessary have to run it with CMD.exe you could just do:

```
& ping.exe doesnotexist ; Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE
```

Applied to your command line program:

```
& cmd.exe /c 'D:\SQL2008R2\SQL2008R2\setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=sqlconfig.ini && exit 0 || exit 1'
```

Or just:

```
& D:\SQL2008R2\SQL2008R2\setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=sqlconfig.ini
```

In both cases `$LASTEXITCODE` should be 0 for success, non-zero otherwise (if the external program was written correctly).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you could do that as well. I wanted mine to be in a new window, though. So I needed `Start-Process`

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it: `start` is actually an alias `Start-Process`, so you have to look at *it's* documentation, which is a lot different than cmd.exe's `start`. So you can do this:

```
(Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe /c ..." -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

So easy!

Comment: Keep in mind that, that will simply write it to the pipeline. If you want to echo it to StdOut, you would use the Write-Host cmdlet.

Comment: This was a false positive. As it turns out, this only works if you remove the `start cmd "/c` part. It worked for me because I had been trying both in my PowerShell session. Command prompt still isn't returning anything..

Answer (score 0):

Too late maybe but does this help?

```
start /WAIT cmd.exe /C "YOUR-COMMAND-HERE" & if errorlevel 1 echo 'error occurred'
```

you can also explicitly return an error code like this:

```
start /WAIT cmd.exe /C "YOUR-COMMAND-HERE & exit MY-ERROR-CODE" & if errorlevel 1 echo 'error occurred'
```