# Running 7-Zip from within a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm trying to use 7-Zip to backup some files inside a Powershell (v2) script.

I have:

```
$zipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
[Array]$zipArgs = "-mx=9 a", "`"c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip`"", "`"c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt`""

&$zipPath $zipArgs;
```

But when I run this I get:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


Error:
Incorrect command line
```

Writing this to the screen I get:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe -mx=9 a "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip" "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
```

So I assumed that I needed to put quotes around the path to 7z.exe, that gave me:

```
$zipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipPath = " `"$zipPath`" "
[Array]$zipArgs = "-mx=9 a", "`"c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip`"", "`"c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt`""

&$zipPath $zipArgs;
```

But then I get the following error:

```
    The term '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is c
orrect and try again.
At C:\BackupScript\Backup.ps1:45 char:22
+                     & <<<< `"$zipPath`" $zipArgs;                    
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe":String) [], CommandNotFound 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Writing it out gives me:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx=9 a "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip" "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
```

Which works as expected when pasting straight into a command window.
I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but assume I am missing something (probably quite obvious). Can anybody see what I need to do to make this run?

Comment: An article I wrote recently may be helpful: [Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell). Try `& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "-mx=9" a C:\BackupFolder\Backup.zip C:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt`.

Comment: Cheers, that's an interesting article. I'll need to have a proper read later. I think that you may have the answer. Whereas I had `"-mx=9 a"` what I needed was `"-mx=9" a`. I can't make it work with $zipArgs variable, but it does work with     `& "$zipPath" "-mx=9" a "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip" "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"`

Comment: Correct; to prevent PowerShell from interpreting `-mx=9` as an operator, use quotes or escape the parameter with a backtick (as explained in the article).

Comment: Try `&$zipPath @zipArgs`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Found [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-and-7Zip-83020e74) script and adapted it to your needs. Can you please try:

```
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $7zipPath -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "7 zip file '$7zipPath' not found"
}

Set-Alias Start-SevenZip $7zipPath

$Source = "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
$Target = "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip"

Start-SevenZip a -mx=9 $Target $Source
```

Comment: Cheers for that. I got that working. I'll need to spend some time with that syntax is I'm not familiar with it (it's always good to learn new ways of doing things). cheers

Comment: Nice cheeky bit of alias work there which really helps make calls to 7z much easier. Thanks!

Comment: While I am not suggesting that aliases are always a good thing, one could also call it `7z`. `set-alias 7z "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"`

Comment: Docs at https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm. They helped me figured out that I needed to cd into the directory to avoid parent folders being copied to the zip.

Answer (score 16):

put "&" special character before 7z command. Example: &7z ...

Answer (score 14):

Simply prefix the command with an ampersand

```
& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx=9 a "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip" "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simpler solution is to run 7-zip on your Powershell via `cmd`:

```
cmd /c 7za ...
```

Comment: I might try it! I notice ps's $LASTEXITCODE [1] should get the nice return code [2] too. ; Refs. 1.[] ; X.Returning an error code from CMD to Powershell - Stack Overflow ;; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004666/returning-an-error-code-from-cmd-to-powershell ; 2.[] ; X.Exit Codes from 7-Zip ;; http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you adapt it correctly: Dont forget the "" on "$Target"
and avoid $7zipPath in c:\programm files with a space in the path

```
Set-Alias 7zip $7zipPath

$Source = "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
$Target = "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip"

7zip a -mx=9 "$Target" "$Source"
```

or

```
7z a "$ArchiveName" -t7z '@listfile.txt'
```

Comment: Quotes didn't work for me. I had to cd into the directory to avoid the parent folders being dumped into the archive https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm

Answer (score 0):

try to use parameter -file to specify the location of program or script:

-file "C:\Program Files\someting.exe"

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\'Program files'\7-Zip\7z.exe a '$archiveFile'  -Path '$dest'
```

where:

- `archiveFile` = name of the archive file name.
- `dest` = destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because each command line option needs to be a separate element in the array, so

```
[Array]$zipArgs = "-mx=9", "a", "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip", "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
```

instead of

```
[Array]$zipArgs = "-mx=9 a", "c:\BackupFolder\backup.zip", "c:\BackupFrom\backMeUp.txt"
```

Note, that the "a" needs to be a separate element. Also the filenames do not need embedded quotes in them (they might if they included spaces, I'm not sure).