# Returning errors from Python to PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm running multiple Python scripts in PowerShell, and I want at specific condition in Python script to notify PowerShell main script. Like throwing an error from Python and catching it with PowerShell.

Python example:

```
import os
print "Running Python script ..."
raise Exception("This Error is coming from Python")
```

And PowerShell main script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    python runThisScript.py -ErrorAction Stop
    # Write-Error -Message 'Oh no! An error!'
    Write-Host "What is that?"
} catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Green
    throw [System.Exception] "Python scrip XXX failed"
} finally {
    Write-Host "This is the final block ..."
}
```

But this does not work. It will show:

```
Running Python script ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runThisScript.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception("This Error is coming from Python")
Exception: This Error is coming from Python
What is that?
This is the final block ...
```

If I un-comment the line `Write-Error -Message 'Oh no! An error!'` this is what I want to see (the error is catch and handle by PowerShell).

```
Oh no! An error!
This is the final block ...
Python scrip XXX failed
At C:\Automation\general_stuff\tc\mainTestRunner.ps1:12 char:5
+     throw [System.Exception] "Python scrip XXX failed"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Python scrip XXX failed
```

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: You can utilize return codes and capture outputs. `$out = python script.py; if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { $out }`

Comment: This is pretty close to on point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004666/returning-an-error-code-from-cmd-to-powershell.  See the highest upvoted answer.  @TheIncorrigible1's comment is the TL;DR version of the answer as well.

Comment: Indeed, this it works. Thank you @TheIncorrigible1 and Matthew!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - want to post an answer for him to accept, or dupe to another question?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I think it's close enough to be a duplicate since implementation is equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an error code from CMD to Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004666/returning-an-error-code-from-cmd-to-powershell)

Comment: I don't agree with Duplicate in this case. My question was about a way to communicate between Python and PowerShell. `$LASTEXITCODE` is an workaround, not a direct way. Also, there are more ways to do the same thing: in Python, log the notification in a text file then when is finish, read the notification from log file directly in PowerShlell ... same result, different approach.

Comment: I don't see how python could return an exception to powershell unless it were a cmdlet.  If ($lastexiitcode) { throw ... } ?